# Scale an entire WPF window

Tags: .net, wpf, resolution-independence

I have a WPF application that I am going to be demoing to an audience on a large, high-resolution projector, and I am worried that the application will be too small to see from afar.

Is there a simple way to make the ENTIRE application bigger (like the zoom slider in the WPF designer, that lets you zoom in?)  I tried adding a layout transform to the Window in XAML, like so:

```
<Window.LayoutTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" />
</Window.LayoutTransform>
```

which makes the window look bigger in the designer, but seems to have no effect on the running application.

I figure this should be dead simple with WPF's "resolution independence", high-tech text rendering, vector graphics, etc.

(I know I can use a screen zooming tool, but that's lame since it makes everything fuzzy, and always makes me dizzy when the presenter pans around the screen.)

Comment: I think you might want a `RenderTransform` rather than a `LayoutTransform`.

Comment: @Gabe: `RenderTransform` is not allowed on a `Window` (throws XamlParseException).  And I really do want to do a `LayoutTransform` anyway, since I want the controls to all be bigger, and push each other bigger (e.g. the `Grids` need to grow, the `StackPanels` need to grow).  I know that `LayoutTransforms` are slower, but this is a line-of-business application where there are few animations and performance is not critical.

Comment: I agree with Gabe.  An entire ui  window can be scaled from a mainwindow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I posted a fairly detailed example of scaling the main element [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193339/tips-on-developing-resolution-independent-application/5000120#5000120). Perhaps it would be of some use to you.

Comment: This basically boils down to putting the `LayoutTransform` on the top-level grid, but you've done a lot more work to make it adjustable at runtime.  All I wanted was a quick thing I could to to compile at higher size, but this is a better general-purpose solution.

Answer (score 13):

Just realized that putting the transform on the *top-level control* (a `Grid`, in my case), instead of on the *window itself*, has a similar effect to what I was looking for.  The only difference is that the window size doesn't change so everything looks a little cramped, but that is easily remedied by making the window larger.

Comment: old post, but could the Window-Property SizeToContent help in "crampled view". should always resize the window to the actual content size.

Answer (score 5):

Using [ViewBox](http://wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html) would be the simplest way to make an entire application bigger, even the font size.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716298/is-the-viewbox-the-best-thing-to-use-to-achieve-resolution-independence-in-wpf?rq=1) you can find some discussion about ViewBox.

Comment: People always forget the ViewBox. It solves so many problems!

Answer (score 5):

## Working Solution

At least in WPF .NET Core 3.1 `Window` supports `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`, it may work with older versions also as this property is supported since .NET Framework 3.0.
Combined with a **fixed width/height** of the content control and a `ScaleTransform` set on `LayoutTransform`, it **scales the entire window**.

## Recipe

- Window

  - `SizeToContent`: `WidthAndHeight`
- Content

  - Fixed size
  - `LayoutTransform`: your custom `ScaleTransform`

### Note

Setting `SizeToContent` by a **style doesn't work** (seems too late in the process).

## Sample XAML

```xml
<Window x:Class="Some.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Some"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ScaleTransform x:Key="windowScaleTransform" ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Width="1080" 
          Height="1920" 
          LayoutTransform="{StaticResource windowScaleTransform}"
          >
        <TextBlock>This window is scaled to 50%!</TextBlock>        
    </Frame>
</Window>
```

Comment: it works,Sizetocontent did not work as expected,so i reset the size of the window